# Can 'native to...' be combined with a non-specific place?

Tags: word-usage

One of my pupils wrote 'The blue mud dragon is native to high places, such as the Himalayas and the Rocky Mountains'.

My question is whether this use of 'native to' is common. I feel that it can only be combined with a specific place and not something general like 'high places'.

Comment: I am a native speaker of English from NYC. I have never seen anything that would imply that 'native to...' must refer to specific locations, nor would I perceive a construction like your student's to be in any way unusual.

Comment: There are quite a few examples of such usage too: [1](https://www.physiology.org/doi/abs/10.1152/jappl.1985.58.1.193), [2](https://homeguides.sfgate.com/plant-yucca-aloifolia-25278.html), and [3](https://darinslakeareablog.wordpress.com/2018/01/30/succulents/). Not all of these are formally reviewed publications but you can see the usage is idiomatic and widespread.

Comment: Thanks a lot @JeffZeitlin.

Answer (score 1):

I have never seen anything that would imply that 'native to...' must refer to specific locations, nor would I perceive a construction like your student's to be in any way unusual.

There are quite a few examples of such usage too: [physiology.org1](https://www.physiology.org/doi/abs/10.1152/jappl.1985.58.1.193), [homeguides](https://homeguides.sfgate.com/plant-yucca-aloifolia-25278.html), and [darins lake area blog](https://darinslakeareablog.wordpress.com/2018/01/30/succulents/).  You can see the usage is idiomatic and widespread.